# An error about outArgument in wf

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I got the following error when I declare an `OutArgument` inside an activity using a bookmark!

> "value of required activity argument 'Out-arg' was not supplied"

Here's my code:

```
public string BookmarkName = "bookmark1 NameBookmark";        

[RequiredArgument]
public OutArgument<String> Out_arg { get; set; }

protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
    context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkName, new BookmarkCallback(OnBookmarkCallback));

    // Out_arg = new System.Activities.OutArgument<System.String>((string)val);
    // new ArgumentReference<string>("Out_arg");
}

protected override bool CanInduceIdle
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void OnBookmarkCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object val)
{
     // Out_arg = new System.Activities.OutArgument<System.String>((string)val);
     // Out_arg = new OutArgument<String>((string)val);
     // Out_arg = ((string)val);
     Out_arg = new OutArgument<string>(new VisualBasicReference<string>((string)val));
}
```

[image: First result]

[image: Second result]

thank you.

Comment: I would suggest reading a book or watching some screencasts about WF4 first. For example[Pro WF: Windows Workflow in .NET 4.0](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WF-Windows-Workflow-NET/dp/1430227214/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1310982776&sr=8-1) or [Beginning WF: Windows Workflow in .NET 4.0](http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-WF-Windows-Workflow-Experts/dp/1430224851/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1310982776&sr=8-2) or [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wf-screencasts) videos I did for the MSDN site.

Comment: If you plan on developing .NET professionally, I'd strongly suggest you read the [Framework Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) guidelines

Comment: Thanks, but i cant pay for them. when i tried to do the following :         Variable<string> w = new Variable<string>("tryiing");
        Out_arg= w; it shows me error says:outArgument is a property but used as type. what is this means?

Answer (score 5):

I get the feeling you're a new .NET developer.  WF4 isn't exactly the easiest thing to jump into when you're new to development.  There are a number of not-obvious design patterns which the framework uses, which only experienced developers will grasp.  I say this not because I'm awesome (although, quite frankly...) but because the documentation isn't clear, and there aren't many resources out there about WF4 yet.

Nevertheless, you are misunderstanding how In/OutArguments are handled in WF4.  You must `set` the argument prior to [CacheMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activity.cachemetadata.aspx) is called, and then use the [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.argument.set.aspx) and [Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465871.aspx) methods of the argument to set/get the value of the argument at runtime.

**The WF4 Arguments pattern is:**  The Workflow runtime needs to know what your Activity is planning to do and must provide a way for the Workflow to handle the important *dynamic* data (data which changes during runtime) your Activity needs to operate.  The Workflow runtime must be in change of storing this data at runtime and serializing/deserializing it.

In order for the Workflow to do this, it gives you In/Out/InOutArguments (and Variables) in which you can store your volatile data.  During the call to `CacheMetadata`, the Workflow learns about these instances and prepares the facilities needed for you to access them at runtime.  ***If you make changes to these properties after the call to CacheMetadata, the Workflow can no longer get/set/serialize/deserialize the data these instances contain***.

You therefore must set these once and never change these instances again.  You can do this via the constructor or by implementing [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx).

Here's a simple example:

```
public sealed class Negate : NativeActivity<bool>, IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<bool> Input { get; set; }

    public Negate() 
    {
        // set it within the constructor option
        //Input = new InArgument<bool>();
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddArgument(Input);
        metadata.AddArgument(Result);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
         // note the use of Get and Set methods
         Result.Set(context, !Input.Get(context));
    }

    Activity IActivityTemplateFactory.Create(DependencyObject target)
    { 
        // or we can set the Arguments here
        return new Negate 
        {
            Input = new InArgument<bool>(),
            Result = new OutArgument<bool>()
        };
    }
}
```

`IActivityTemplateFactory.Create` is called when the Activity is dropped on the design surface.  Once dropped, the Arguments are created, which happens before `CacheMetadata` is called.  This is the best way to configure these, imho.  Using the constructor can lead to some unexpected behavior.  Note how we are telling the runtime in `CacheMetadata` about the properties we want the runtime to track for us.  Once the method is called, we never change the instance held within those properties.  We can only call methods (such as `Get` and `Set`) on them.

**Edit:**  Here's a simple example of when these methods are called.

- User drags Activity from the toolbox and drops it on the design surface
- Create method is called (creates the Activity on the design surface)
- CacheMetadata is called
- User enters the value of Input
- CacheMetadata is called
- User builds the solution
- CacheMetadata is called
- User runs the solution
- An instance of the workflow is created
- CacheMetadata is called
- Workflow executes
- Execute is called
- InArgument.Get is called
- OutArgument.Set is called
- Workflow completes execution

Comment: You are awesome, quite frankly. May you recommend some books for me, as an beginner of .net developer to become a guru like you?

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE I'm just an accolyte.  Not near guru status.  The first book you should read is CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter.  This will give you insight not only in how to program C#, but also how the CLR operates and what the compiler does to your code.  Next, pick up a copy of the Framework Guidelines.  They instruct you on design patterns and conventions you should follow to be a good .net developer.  After you've done that, program for five years.  Then you'll be pretty steady on your feet.

Comment: Dear Will, Thank you for your recommendation and I already borrowed the CLR via C# which will be on my desk for a long time. I am developing a WPF app and encounter a problem. May you have time to have a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804024/invokemethod-of-windows-workflow-4-can-encounter-exception-c0000005   thank you so much in advance!